# Hidden values show up as blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, angularjs

I have a form using rails and being submitted by angularjs. The problem I'm having is that when I try to access the form data from angular, the input that is not hidden will show up in the form newTask object, but the fields that are hidden won't. Is there something I am missing here?

```
= form_for [@patient, Task.new], html: {action: nil, name: 'newTaskForm', 'ng-submit' => 'taskCreate($event, newTask)'} do |f|

= f.hidden_field :taskable_id, :value => @patient.id, 
'ng-model' => 'newTask.taskable_id'

= f.hidden_field :taskable_type, :value => @patient.class.to_s,
'ng-model' => 'newTask.taskable_type'

= f.hidden_field :creator_id, :value => current_user.id,
'ng-model' => 'newTask.creator_id'

= f.text_field :text, required: true, placeholder: 'Add a task...',
'ng-model' => 'newTask.text'

= f.submit 'Add task', 'ng-disabled' => 'newTaskForm.$invalid'
```